# Removing Perl Catalyst framework

Tags: perl, catalyst

Is there a simple way to uninstall [Perl's Catalyst framework](http://catalyst.perl.org)?

It seems like there are tons of ways to [install it](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aInstallation), but not much on cleanly removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPAN is your friend - https://metacpan.org/module/pm-uninstall

Comment: Be careful uninstalling dependencies. They may bb dependencies for other things you need too.